# unreachable host on mininet using openflow controller

Tags: mininet, openflow

I have this topology in python for use in a controller that implements open flow.

```
class complex_topo(Topo):
  def build(self):

      h10 = self.addHost('h10',mac='00:00:00:00:00:10',ip='10.0.1.10', defaultRoute="h10-eth0")
      h20 = self.addHost('h20',mac='00:00:00:00:00:20',ip='10.0.2.20', defaultRoute="h20-eth0")
      h30 = self.addHost('h30',mac='00:00:00:00:00:30',ip='10.0.3.30', defaultRoute="h30-eth0")
      h40 = self.addHost('h40',mac='00:00:00:00:00:40',ip='10.0.4.40', defaultRoute="h40-eth0")
      h50 = self.addHost('h50',mac='00:00:00:00:00:50',ip='10.0.5.50', defaultRoute="h50-eth0")
      h60 = self.addHost('h60',mac='00:00:00:00:00:60',ip='10.0.6.60', defaultRoute="h60-eth0")
      h70 = self.addHost('h70',mac='00:00:00:00:00:70',ip='10.0.7.70', defaultRoute="h70-eth0")
      h80 = self.addHost('h80',mac='00:00:00:00:00:80',ip='10.0.8.80', defaultRoute="h80-eth0")
      h90 = self.addHost('h90',mac='00:00:00:00:00:90',ip='10.0.9.10', defaultRoute="svr1-eth0")
      h99 = self.addHost('h99',mac='00:00:00:00:00:99',ip='172.16.10.100', defaultRoute="h99- `enter code here`eth0")

      s1 = self.addSwitch('s1') # floor 1 s1
      s2 = self.addSwitch('s2') # floor 1 s2
      s3 = self.addSwitch('s3') # floor 2 s1
      s4 = self.addSwitch('s4') # floor 2 s2
      s5 = self.addSwitch('s5') # core switch
      s6 = self.addSwitch('s6') #data center switch

      self.addLink(s1, h10, port1=1, port2=1) # floor1sw1 to host 10
      self.addLink(s1, h20, port1=2, port2=1) # floor1sw1 to host 20
      self.addLink(s2, h30, port1=1, port2=1) # floor1sw2 to host 30
      self.addLink(s2, h40, port1=2, port2=1) # floor1sw2 to host 40

      self.addLink(s3, h50, port1=1, port2=1) # floor2sw1 to host 50
      self.addLink(s3, h60, port1=2, port2=1) # floor2sw1 to host 60
      self.addLink(s4, h70, port1=1, port2=1) # floor2sw2 to host 70
      self.addLink(s4, h80, port1=2, port2=1) # floor2sw2 to host 80

      self.addLink(s5, s1, port1=1, port2=3)  # core switch to floor1sw1
      self.addLink(s5, s2, port1=2, port2=3)  # core switch to floor1sw2
      self.addLink(s5, s3, port1=3, port2=3)  # core switch to floor2sw1
      self.addLink(s5, s4, port1=4, port2=3)  # core switch to floor2sw2
      self.addLink(s5, h99, port1=5, port2=1) # core switch to untrustedhost

      self.addLink(s6, h90, port1=1, port2=1) # Data Center Switch to server 1
      self.addLink(s6, s5, port1=3, port2=6)  # Data Center Switch to Core Switch
```

my question is, how do I implement rules in my controller that will allow ip traffic to flow from h99 (out of network host) to the nodes in the network, but not vice versa

Comment: Can you specify which controller are you using?

Comment: REMOTE CONTROLLER

Comment: You have to know how to install the flow with the controller that you are using i.e. Ryu, pox, Onos, etc. But this depends on the controller, not mininet.
If you want to install the rule manually you can use ovs-ofctl add-flow SWITCH FLOW command

Comment: I am using a pox controller.